# Salesforce REST JSON not getting serialized properly?

Tags: apex, community, json, rest

Please help me to get this JSON string deserialize as map of list of string.

```
public static void postPermissionSetAutoDelegation(Map<string,Set<String>> delegationMap,String OrgName)
{
    String jsonstr = (String)JSON.serialize(delegationMap);

    //The JSonStr ->   {"ITL8090":["Administrator:TRUE","Bank_Operations_Reviewer:TRUE"]} 
    //Code skipped Retriving accessToken and instance URL

    String uri = ResponseMap.get('instance_url') + '/services/apexrest/PermSetDelegation/';
    System.debug(uri);
    //Post the data         
    HttpResponse res = send(uri,'HttpPost',jsonstr,ResponseMap.get('access_token')); //End point should be rest service URL
    System.debug('***'+res);
}
```

My Post method in another org

```
@HttpPost  
global static  Map<String, List<String>> processPermSetDelegation()
{
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    Map<String, List<String>> delegationMap= (Map<String, List<String>>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(String.valueOf(req));  //Error         
    system.debug(req);
    return delegationMap;
    //Parse and send the data to handler class
}
```

> Error Message:
>   RESPONSE_BODY[{"errorCode":"APEX_ERROR","message":"System.JSONException:
>   Unexpected character ('R' (code 82)): expected a valid value (number,
>   String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at input location
>   [1,2]\n\nClass.System.JSON.deserializeUntyped: line 11, column
>   1\nClass.Method processPermSetDelegation:
>   line 9, column 1"}]

Comment: Can you put in an example of your delegation map?

Comment: {"ITL8090":["Administrator:TRUE","Bank_Operations_Reviewer:TRUE"]}

Comment: Pretty sure you need to get the body before trying to deserialize it - ie `String reqBody = req.getBody(); then JSON.deserializeUntyped() it. I think the `R` that you are getting is the first letter of the text "Request"

Comment: Added as an answer. I'm fairly sure this will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently trying to deserialize the RestRequst SObject to a Map. Instead, you want to deserialize the RestRequest's **body**, which contains the POSTed data. Here is the API page for the RestRequest class:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_restrequest.htm#apex_methods_system_restrequest.

Using the **request body**, your code would then look something like this:

```
@HttpPost  
global static  Map<String, List<String>> processPermSetDelegation()
{
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    String requestBody = req.requestBody.toString();
    System.debug(requestBody);
    Map<String, List<String>> delegationMap = (Map<String, List<String>>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(requestBody);        
    System.debug(delegationMap);
    return delegationMap;
    //Parse and send the data to handler class
}
```

However, I advise posting **params** and then retrieving them via the RestRequest.params property.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you need to get the body before trying to deserialize it.

Try this:

```
@HttpPost  
global static  Map<String, List<String>> processPermSetDelegation(){
RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
Map<String, List<String>> delegationMap= 
    (Map<String, List<String>>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(String.valueOf(req.getBody()));    
....
```